# Get the filepath of an image inserted into TWebBrowser in edit mode

Tags: delphi

When you insert an image into a TWebBrowser in edit mode, how do you get the filepath of the inserted image?  When an image is inserted it includes the full path to the image in the html source, but in my case I need to modify the html source to only include the filename.

**EDIT:**
This is the html source after the image is inserted:

```
<IMG border=0 hspace=0 alt=delphi align=baseline 
src="C:\Images\delphi.bmp">
```

I need to change

```
<IMG border=0 hspace=0 alt=delphi align=baseline 
src="C:\Images\delphi.bmp">
```

to

```
<IMG border=0 hspace=0 alt=delphi align=baseline 
src="HTML\delphi.bmp">
```

Yes I can get the path from the html but I'd like to try to copy the image file to the HTML folder then change the path to the HTML folder after the image is inserted without parsing the html.  If the filepath can be obtained after the image is inserted I can add the code to copy the file to the HTML folder so that the image appears in the webbrowser with the new path...

Comment: please be more specific. are you trying to update an `IMG` tag `src` attribute after you insert it (or before)?

Comment: _"When an image is inserted it includes the full path to the image in the html source"_ so can't you get it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the browser's DOM interfaces to read the `src` attribute and update it to what you want? Specifically, look at the `src` property of the [`IHTMLImgElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752250.aspx) interface.

Comment: How do you get the 'src' of the image what was JUST inserted?